# Injecting and executing JavaScript string in a specific HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have received the latest Disqus comments string (JavaScript code) from the server using ajax call that has `document.write` code in it.

I want the page to execute this code inside a specific DIV (by it Id, which is '`#recent-comments`') in the page, how do I do that?

I use jQuery 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit nasty but you could eval it inside a closure function:

```
var message =" document.write('hello'); ";


eval("(function(){"+
     "var document = {write:function(text){$('#divName').html(text)}}; " +
     message +
     "  })();");
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9uwbnerg/) (I've had to change write to wrie otherwise jsfiddle disallows it, just need to change back for your case)

Comment: it should be injected into a specific html element

Comment: It does now, and with demo

Answer (score 0):

Since it is coming as a string, you need to create a script element and put the string (inside document.write) as a element to the div.

```
var sampleStr = "document.write(\"Hello World\");";
var str, scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
str = sampleStr.replace(/["']/g, '"');
str = str.replace(/"document.write/g, "");
scriptElement.innerHTML = str;
$('#div1').append(scriptElement);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tLjf0ss/2/)

Comment: it write the string, doesn't execute it. I see in the page like "document.write(' \ \" as text. The document.write should be executed.

Comment: no, document.write is a javascipt command (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp). This is a javascript code that should run on the client to render the comments. I get the code via the API. All that I need is a away to execute it inside a specific DIV, and it will render there.

Comment: aaggh sry for that, is it enclosed with <script> tag as well?

Comment: no, it start like so "↵↵document.write(' " (without the quotes)

Comment: It doesn't run the code. t puts the code in the html but it doesn't render on the screen. On the page it's an empty space. Furthermore, there are slashes in the injected code. Here's an image: http://postimg.org/image/l6rv5pfht/

Comment: whats the id of the container that you having @IdanShechter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71003/discussion-between-v31-and-idan-shechter).